# The field 'Author' of type 'User' cannot be used in the query filter expression

Tags: filter, user-accounts, odata, rest

I was making a rest api call with Odata filter author/id. I want to get survey responses of a particular user.

```
_api/Web/Lists(guid'id')/items?$select=Id,Author/ID&$expand=Author/ID&$filter=(Author/ID eq 21)
```

But I am getting an error :

```
The field 'Author' of type 'User' cannot be used in the query filter expression.
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

You are missing ID in `expand`. The query should look like:
_`api/Web/Lists(guid'id')/items?$select=Id,Author/ID&$expand=Author/ID&$filter=(Author/ID eq 21)`

Comment: I added ID also in expand. Even then it is not working. Throwing the same error

Comment: try using   `&$filter=Author/ID eq '21'` or `&$filter=Author/ID eq 21`

Comment: Same error. Is this author a reserve keyword or something?

Comment: As per the last comment in this blog post http://sympmarc.com/2014/01/21/getting-user-information-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/, Author can be used in filter expression: `&$filter=Author/FirstName eq 'Shelly'`

Comment: Same error. Not working.

Comment: Aren't you getting this information from "User Information List". If not what is the name of your lookup field and to what field of lookup list is it attached to?

Comment: Yes. Information is getting from "User Information List". But it is not allowing to filter the list by author id

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `$expand` operator if you don't need to return the projected fields.

The following REST endpoint demonstrates how to filter by Author Id:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Tasks')/items?$filter=(AuthorId eq 12)
```

Comment: Am getting below error: Column 'AuthorId' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user. /Lists/Map functionality

Comment: Make sure you have an Author field in your list

Comment: yes. It is there if we select all fields of that list. I doubt SharePoint use it internally

Answer (score 0):

You can update your query as

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Tasks')/items?$filter=(Author eq 12)
```

The SharePoint **REST** removes the Id appended to any of the **lookup Field** or **people-picker**